# Trying to get a page layout to work with Google mobile-friendly tests

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My first post after much searching on the forum, so please be gentle with me!

I have a 20 year-old website that needs to be made mobile-friendly in the easiest way possible, principally through css (the site has almost 2200 pages so far, so manually editing individual pages is next to impossible).

Getting even the simplest of those pages to be classed as mobile-friendly by Google seems to be impossible without sacrificing some layout requirements. In this case, centring the content seems to result in a 'Page is not mobile friendly' fail result from Google.

I have rewritten the old html and for now have hard-written the css into the page until I get it working and can transfer it to a css sheet.

I've used 320px as the div width because that gave me a good starting point with Google's test. But centring the page content using "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" generates a Google mobile test failure. Take it out and the page passes.

Change the div to 100% and setting the image width to 320px passes, but it also removes page-centring. Then increasing the image width to suit larger mobile displays generates a Google fail. I seem to be going round in circles so I could do with some advice.

The code below shows where the page is now - centred but generating a Google fail because content doesn't fit the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<base target="_top" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="text-align: center; overflow-x: hidden;">

<div style="width: 320px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="Popup1">
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
    <img border="0" src="../images/Americas/North/Native_Powhatan_Tribe01_max.jpg" alt="Test" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;" height="auto"><!-- Image width is 1000px --></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the live version of the page in its current state:
http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsAmericas/NorthPowhatan_Tribe01_Full.htm

This is the testing microsite version of the page, with all my edits:
http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/microsite_live/KingListsAmericas/NorthPowhatan_Tribe01_Full.htm

(It's the picture sizing and container that seems to be the problem area, so everything else has been stripped out for now).

Comment: You are in "quirks mode" with a doctype that no one should be using since 1999 at least. Your markup also contains obsolete attributes and numerous other issues.

Comment: The site literally is that old, as mentioned.

I'm not a professional web developer and certainly can't handle a massive rebuilt for 2200-odd pages, even though most of those are in three main standard page styles. All I can do it try and provide a latest fix to try and improve presentation and indexing status.

Removing the doctype produced an additional issue in the page layout - a form of padding in the History Files title bar above the main image. This bar is visible in the live version of the page as it should be, and in the testing version with the padding now visible (at 19:05 GMT).

Comment: A doctype is *required* for all web pages today. Removing it will only make things worse as you found out. The problem is, you are trying to add modern features using an incompatible doctype and that will only introduce boatloads of fun.

Comment: Agreed, but that's the boat I'm in so I'm going to have to make the most of it. I can't rebuild the boat while it's still at sea (to stretch the metaphor a bit too far!). The goal is to make the site acceptable to Google so that visitor numbers are restored to the previous average of 5500 unique views per day. Perhaps there's a better 'quirks mode' doctype than the one I've been using for the last two decades...? I'm no programmer and I don't particularly enjoy it. Researching and writing the content is what really interests me so this process is a painful necessity rather than a joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BODY` has default margin/padding values. First, reset them `margin:0;padding:0` and add `width:100%` for full-width/fit-to-screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/microsite_live/css/history_mainstyles.css" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="noindex, follow" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<base target="_top" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<style type="text/css" media="all" />
@import "http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/microsite_live/css/history_substyles.css";
</style>

</head>
<!-- I changed this line. -->
<body style="width:100%;margin:0;padding:0">

<div style="width:320px;margin:0 auto">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="Popup1">
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
    <img border="0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500/4B89DA/F4F6F9" alt="Test" width="100%"><!-- Image width is 1000px --></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" height="10">
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">

 <p class="popuptitle">Captain John Smith</p>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">

 <p class="popup">John Smith is shown in this illustration trading 
 with the native Americans who resided close to James Fort, probably 
 in 1607-1608, although his explorations took him much further afield, 
    across the northern edge of Chesapeake Bay and into Susquehannock 
    territory.</p>

 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" height="70">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%">

    <p class="popup">Original text copyright © P L Kessler and the 
    History Files. Image copyright © respective copyright holders. 
    An original photo page for the History Files. Go 
    <a href="javascript:history.back()">back</a> or return 
    <a target="_top" href="../index.html">home</a>.</p>

 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" height="70">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="100%" bgcolor="#141414">

 <!-- Footer links -->
 <p class="navftr" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Copyright © 1999-2018 <a href='http://www.kessler-web.co.uk/' target='_blank'><span class='navftr'>Kessler Associates.</span></a> All rights reserved.</p>

 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The website has basic BODY settings in the main css stylesheet which remove any default margin, but not the padding which I ddn't know about. The changes make the page a Google pass, but that's probably because the page centring option has been nullified. The page is now left-aligned.